# Need help in setup `ion-nav-view` inside ionic modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am bit new to ionic development.

I am using ionic's default sidemenu template.

I want to create navigation flow inside modal. Modal is intended to use for login. And login page linked with forgot password and signup page through navigation.

**What I have done so far is**,

Modified app.js `stateprovider` and added some new routes. I am partially succeeded in it but when `$state.go('loginnav.login');` that code executes I got login view embedded in my app/main navigation flow not inside modal's navigation flow.

**Issue :** I am not able to give navigation flow inside login Modal.

Any help would be greatly apprecieated.

`app.js`

```
.state('loginnav', {
    url: '/loginnav',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/loginnav.html',
})

.state('loginnav.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
    'logContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('loginnav.signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    views: {
    'logContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html'
        }
    }
})
```

`loginnav.html`

```
<ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="logContent" ng-controller="LoginNavCtrl"></ion-nav-view>
```

`controller.js -> AppCtrl`

```
// Create the login modal that we will use later
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/loginnav.html', {
scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
$scope.modal = modal;
});
```

`controller.js -> LoginNavCtrl`

```
$state.go('loginnav.login');
```

Comment: I have posted same question in ionic forum and got answer as follow.

"So this isn't possible currently with ionic v1. It's a limitation of how urls and routing are tied together."

Link : http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/need-help-in-setup-ion-nav-view-inside-ionic-modal/35679